# How to pass inputs automatically to a child shell script that is invoked from a parent shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am new to shell scripting and I have a scenario where I want to pass inputs to a shell script invoked from another shell script.

Lets say script1 when executed prompts for input y or n

```
bash>./script1.sh
     Executing .....
     Do you want to continue (y/n)?
```

to achieve this i have passed the input as part of a file as below.

```
bash>./script1.sh < input.txt
```

Similarly if there is a shell script2.sh invoked from script1.sh, how do i pass the input.txt to script2 for providing inputs?

```
./script1.sh < input.txt
```

Comment: You can use utils like [tag:expect] (for [tag:tcl]) and [tag:pexpect] (for [tag:python]). Or try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) (for shells).

Answer (score 0):

subprocesses inherit the stdin/stdout/stderr from their parent, so indeed, you dont have to do anything. Providing "input.txt" as stdin to a parent script "shell1.sh" will automatically supply that input to any child processes reading from stdin.

Imagine you wouldn't have redirected any input: everything (sub procs or not) would have to read from console.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to save input to a text file. It can just be stored as a variable using `read`. The input can then either pass to `script2` as argument, or `export` it to child processes.

Sample script1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Executing ....."
read -p "Do you want to continue (y/n)? " script1Input
export script1Input
./script2.sh
```

Sample script2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$script1Input" = "y" ]; then
    echo "Input from script1 was yes"
else
    echo "Input from script1 was not yes"
fi
```

When you call script1:

```
$ ./script1.sh
Executing .....
Do you want to continue (y/n)? y
Input from script 1 was yes
```